# In a D3 tree, how to close all nodes at a selected depth (ex. only grandchildren) programmatically (without clicking on a node)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Here's an example. I can figure it out in the click function maybe, but I'm not sure the best way to check all of the children from the root from outside of the click function. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="collapseNodeAtDepth(2)">Close nodes at depth 2</button>
<script>

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level depth 0",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A depth 1",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A depth 2",
        "children": [
          { "name": "grandson of A depth 3" },
          { "name": "grandaughter of A depth 3" }
        ]
       },
          { "name": "Daughter of A depth 2" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B depth 1" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }

function collapseNodeAtDepth(depth){
// 
}
}

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

</style>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="collapseNodeAtDepth(2)">Close nodes at depth 2</button>
<script>

    var treeData =
    {
        "name": "Top Level depth 0",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Level 2: A depth 1",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "Son of A depth 2",
                        "children": [
                            { "name": "grandson of A depth 3" },
                            { "name": "grandaughter of A depth 3" }
                        ]
                    },
                    { "name": "Daughter of A depth 2" }
                ]
            },
            { "name": "Level 2: B depth 1" }
        ]
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("
                    + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
        if(d.children) {
            d._children = d.children
            d._children.forEach(collapse)
            d.children = null
        }
    }

    function update(source) {

        // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
        var treeData = treemap(root);

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
                links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

        // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

        // Update the nodes...
        var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

        // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on('click', click);

        // Add Circle for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('r', 1e-6)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

        // Add labels for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('text')
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

        // UPDATE
        var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        // Transition to the proper position for the node
        nodeUpdate.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

        // Update the node attributes and style
        nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                })
                .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


        // Remove any exiting nodes
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                })
                .remove();

        // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
        nodeExit.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 1e-6);

        // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
        nodeExit.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

        // ****************** links section ***************************

        // Update the links...
        var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr('d', function(d){
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                });

        // UPDATE
        var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

        // Transition back to the parent element position
        linkUpdate.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

        // Remove any exiting links
        var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                })
                .remove();

        // Store the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function(d){
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
        });

        // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
        function diagonal(s, d) {

            path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

            return path
        }

        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }

        collapse = function(node, depth) {
            if(node.depth === depth) node._children = node.children || node._children;
            if(node.depth < depth) node.children = node.children || node._children;
            if(!node.children) return;
            node.children.forEach(function(n){
                collapse(n, depth);
            });

        };

        collapseNodeAtDepth = function (depth){
            collapse(root, depth);
            update(root);
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
```

You could do depth first search from root. See the collapse function.